# .htaccess make subdomain the main domain without moving

Tags: .htaccess

I have my website in a subdomain:

```
subdomain.mydomain.co.uk
```

Now, I don't want to move subdomain.mydomain.co.uk but I want to use .htaccess to set it so that when someone types: mydomain.co.uk the url still remains mydomain.co.uk but acually shows subdomain.mydomain.co.uk

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.co.uk [NC,OR]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

You could try doing an R=301, but beware of the dangers of using a 301 redirect. We had huge problems with our website at one point using 301 redirects as written about in this article: http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/

Comment: I've changed it but no change has happened. Do I need to restart apache?